# Trying to log into website with selenium throws either TimeoutException or ElementNotInteractableException

Tags: python, selenium

I am having issues logging into the website (memodo.de/login) since the login form is not interactable. With my code, I get either a timeout exception or a ElementNotinteractable Exception.

Please see here the html code for the website as well as my current code. I would appreciate if someone could help me with the issue.

I already tried using the execute_script command, without any luck.

Thank you!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import time
import os


driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://www.memodo.de/login')

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='email']"))).send_keys("email")
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='passwort']"))).send_keys("password")
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']"))).click()
```

[HTML Code for the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aWmQ.png)

Comment: Please do not post images of code. You can copy the HTML from the browser's HTML inspector and paste it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

The `xpaths` you are trying are `highlighting` many Elements in the DOM. The `email` and `password` are highlighting 2 Elements each and the `submit` button is highlighting 5 Elements in the DOM.

The locators we use to find the Elements should be unique that is 1/1 which is visible next to the xpath in the DOM. [Link to Refer](https://automationpanda.com/2019/01/15/web-element-locators-for-test-automation/) Go through the `How do I write good locators` for more clarity.

You can try like below.

```
driver.get("https://www.memodo.de/login")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
email = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='register--login-email']/input")))
email.send_keys("Email@email.com")

password = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='register--login-password']/input")))
password.send_keys("password")

submit = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//form[@id='login--form']//button")))
submit.click()
```

You can use these xpaths too.

```
(//input[@id='email'])[2]  # For Email Field  
(//input[@id='passwort'])[2] # For password Field 
//form[@id='login--form']//button # For submit button
```